# How to concurrently send different commands to multiple tmux panes

Tags: tmux

I am connecting to a set of machines, each on a separate tmux pane.

I have a set of commands that I would like to send concurrently, such that each command would be executed on a **different** tmux pane.

Is there any way to do it?

e.g.
The commands:

```
cmdA 
cmdB 
cmdC 
cmdD
```

Send concurrently to different tmux panes

```
shell1> cmdA
______________________________________
shell2> cmdB
______________________________________
shell3> cmdC
______________________________________
shell4> cmdD
______________________________________
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a shell script run commands like

```
tmux send-keys -t 1 'cmdA' enter
tmux send-keys -t 2 'cmdB' enter
tmux send-keys -t 3 'cmdC' enter
tmux send-keys -t 4 'cmdD' enter
```

where `enter` will send the newline character. You need to know the pane numbers, but typically they will be as above.

EDIT: note that `tmux send-keys -t 0 'cmd' enter` sends a command to the active pane

Comment: Thank you! One correction, it looks like `-t 0` send to the active pane rather than the first pane. I will edit your answer to start from the first pane